# Clicking close link on deleted question gives "404" by itself as error text

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, deleted-questions, error-message

After leaving a tab open with a post that got deleted, I accidentally clicked the close button, and got a relatively unexplanatory error message:

[image]

Shouldn't this error popup include a valid english error message or a large piece of polyglot code, at least?